# IAR Expression expression expcted

Tags: c

Programming with IAR EWB. It gave me an error when I tried resetting the array[20]. Task was to record data based on an event. When the event happens, I recorded 6 bytes out of those 20. Next time when the event happens, I recorded next 6 bytes of those 20 and then next 6 bytes. Remaining 2 bytes I ignore.

I declared global array[20]. When the event happens 3 times, I wanted to reset array[20]. One way of doing that is array[20] = {0}. But when I did that it gave me an error saying expression expected. Note that No Macros are involved here.

So I tried using for loop and making each element of array 0 and it worked. I dont understand why. Any thoughts?

Comment: Read [ask], provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you're describing:

```
typename array[20] = {0}
```

can only be used in an initializer, where `array[20]` is a declaration of the array, not a reference to a specific element.

Trying to use this syntax in a statement, e.g.

```
array[20] = {0}
```

reads as if you're trying to set the single element `array[20]` (which is off the end of the array) to `{0}`, which isn't an appropriate value for it.

Use a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That means I have to use the for loop to reset the array[20] to 0. I dont have enough reputation to upvote your answer. Thanks again